# How I can improve redirectioning using route alias

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using devise for an application and I don't like the way my app is redirecting after a successful login. This is `rake routes`'s output:

```
   manager_root GET    /managers/dashboard(.:format)      managers#dashboard
   student_root GET    /students/dashboard(.:format)      students#dashboard
enterprise_root GET    /enterprises/dashboard(.:format)   enterprises#dashboard
```

**What I have so far**

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)               
  "/#{current_user.profile_type.pluralize}/dashboard"
end
```

**What I have tried**

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)               
  "#{current_user.profile_type}"_root_path
end
#=> application_controller.rb:17: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)               
  "#{current_user.profile_type}_root_path"
end
#=> ERROR URI::InvalidURIError: the scheme http does not accept registry part:localhost:3000enterprise_root_path (or bad hostname?)
```

**NOTE**

- I have only one devise model called `User`, and it has a column called `profile_type` whose value can be `'enterprise'`, `'student'` or `'manager'`.
- I just want to use my route alias.
- What I got by far so working I just want to improve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Through [**nash**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/336626/nash)'s answer I searched a better usage of polymorphic and made my own answer.

here is the common way to get the url for post's comments and news' comments

```
# parent may be a post or a news
if Post === parent
  post_comments_path(parent)
elsif News === parent
  news_comments_path(parent)
end
```

Rails provides a simple way to generate the [polymorphic url](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html). So we can use the `polymorphic_path` to get the url for `post`'s and `news`' comments

```
# "/posts/1/comments" or "'news/1/comments"
polymorphic_path([parent, Comment])
```

and this can get the url for post and news

```
# "http://example.com/posts/1/comments" or "http://example.com/news/1/comments"
polymorphic_path(parent)
```

polymorphic_path makes polymorphic url generation much easier and simpler. There is also a method named `polymorphic_url` which is the same as the `polymorphic_path` except that `polymorphic_url` generate the full url including the host name.

Besides these, rails also provides the new and edit action for `polymorphic_path/polymorphic_url`

```
new_polymorphic_path(Post)    # "/posts/new"
new_polymorphic_url(Post)     # "http://example.com/posts/new"
edit_polymorphic_path(post)   # "/posts/1/edit"
edit_polymorphic_url(post)    # "http://example.com/posts/1/edit"
```

In my case, i just

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  polymorphic_path [current_user.profile_type, :root]
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this should work for you:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)               
  polymorphic_url([current_user.profile_type, :root])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)               
  send("#{current_user.profile_type}_root_path")
end
```